# isotope.js and zepto.js (jquery replacment)

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope, zurb-foundation, zepto

I am currently working on a site based on Zurb foundation 4, and I want to introduce isotope.js in the design.
Foundation 4 is using preferably zepto to jquery.

When running a test with isotope, I can't get it work with zepto default library.

I have been able to run my test properly forcing use of jquery.

My question : Is there any current or in development version of isotope running over zepto *(which is lighter)*?

Comment: Looks like Isotope 2 (currently in beta) doesn't need a library anymore : http://isotope.metafizzy.co/beta/methods.html. So it should work with Zepto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for lasting long, finally disabled zepto to go back to jquery in foundation 4.

**My advise then : switch to jquery.**

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at the vanilla versions of either [Masonry.js](http://vanilla-masonry.desandro.com/) or [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/).

Both these version don't require a library to run. I have used both with zepto.js with no issues.